# How can I manually/force install a specific driver in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have recently downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 32-bit and I created a virtual machine using Microsoft Virtual PC (the old one, not the Windows Virtual PC) in order to test it. I did that since my host is an old Pentium 4 PC running Windows XP with only 1GB RAM, so I think Microsoft Virtual PC is the lightest among Oracle Virtualbox and VMWare. I could only give the guest about 360MB. It Works, albeit a little slow. My main problem (apart from speed) is that the virtual graphics hardware is not recognised and I am stuck at 800x600 resolution making use of some applications difficult (buttons not showing etc). I know from Windows that the virtual card is S3, but there are no virtual additions (drivers etc) for Linux and the Ubuntu build-in driver is installed but not used as the hardware is not recognized.

How can I force Ubuntu use specific drivers for the graphics? I know that in a Windows system I would go to Device Manager and manually force/install the S3 graphics driver and would hopefully work. I have done it many times in real PCs with some weird ATI models and it worked. Is there something similar in Ubuntu 32-bit? If this involves the terminal, please give me all the code to copy-paste as I am not familiar with Linux.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually configure the xorg.conf file and choose a specific video driver.

Try one of these:

```
s3 - Old S3 Chipsets
s3virge - S3 ViRGE series (ViRGE, ViRGE DX,GX,GX2,MX,MX+,VX and Trio3D,Trio3D/2x)
savage - S3 Savage series (Savage 3D,4,2000,/MX,/IX, ProSavage PM133,KM133, Twister, TwisterK
```

I would try the standard 's3' driver first.
Here is a very basic xorg.conf file

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    ### Available Driver options are:-
    ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
    ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
    ### <percent>: "<f>%"
    ### [arg]: arg optional
    #Option     "HWcursor"                  # [<bool>]
    #Option     "Xinerama"                  # [<bool>]
    #Option     "StaticXinerama"            # <str>
    #Option     "GuiLayout"                 # <str>
    #Option     "AddDefaultMode"            # [<bool>]
    #Option     "RenderAccel"               # [<bool>]
    #Option     "DRI"                       # [<bool>]
    #Option     "DirectPresents"            # [<bool>]
    #Option     "HWPresents"                # [<bool>]
    #Option     "RenderCheck"               # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "s3"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
EndSection
```

You can save this as xorg.conf and run the command `Xorg -config xorg.conf` to try is out. (you will need to be at the console without X running or you will just get an error.

If that doesn't work for you could you post the contents of your /var/log/Xorg.0.log file?

Comment: @user275069 Also, have you tried their LiveCD for testing?  It works pretty well, albeit slowly off of DVD.